# D3JS - Value of second key is undefined

Tags: d3.js

I'm new in JavaScript and D3.js.

I'm trying to build a heatmap out of a Json that I have nested and rolledup. The resulting array is as the one below:

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
  key:"3"
  values:Array(6)
     0:
       key: "14"
       value:11 
1:
  key:"15"
  value:2
...
```

The final value, in this case 11 and 2 are the result of the following roll up:

```
.rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length;})
```

I need to access all those counts so as the color changes based on that "number", i.e the data.values.value:

```
.style("fill", (d) => colorScale(d.values.value));
```

The issue I get is the console returns it as undefined or NaN depending on the 100 scenarios I have tested (map, each, d3values, etc.). I do get a number when I use the function that I got from Gerardo Furtado. But impossible to have the number only, not the max, for colors purposes.

[D3 js get a d3.max from an object that contains a specific key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930052/d3-js-get-a-d3-max-from-an-object-that-contains-a-specific-key-value)

```javascript
const maxX = d3.max(groupByDayAndHour, function(e) {
    return d3.max(e.values, function(f) {
        return f.value;
    });
});
console.log(maxX, "maxX");
```

Please help. The main questions are: How to access all the "second value"s and how to convert them to a number so as color can dynamically change.

Comment: `d.values.value` is invalid.  `d.values` is an array.  From that array you need a number but you haven't told us which one you want.  You could use the first one, last one, max one, min one, sum them, etc....

Comment: Thank you Jason. I want the last ones, i.e. in my example, the 11 and the 2. The array may contain many of those.

Comment: The last one would be: `.style("fill", (d) => colorScale(d.values[d.values.length-1].value))`

Comment: Issue with that Mark is it returns only the last value of the array, i.e. in my example "2". I would never get the "2" AND the "11". I need to access all "value" of my nested array. I have no problem in accessing the first level of my array, i.e. `values` but as soon as I try to get anything from the second level of my array, i.e. `d.values.value`, I get undefined. For example `d.values.value.count` which I got from my rollup, I get undefined. Not sure it has something to do with this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878072/d3-js-nesting-and-rollup-at-the-same-time-in-v4)

Comment: `I need to access all "value" of my nested array`, this was my original question, how do you want those multiple values represented?  The first one of them, last one, max, min, sum, concatenated into a string, etc...?  You're asking a question only you can answer.

Comment: It took me ages to reach a solution but in case this helps anyone in the future, my solution was found here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502421/d3-js-moving-from-tsv-to-json-with-nested-array). Basically I had to convert my nested structure.